# Boolean not performing as expected

Tags: boolean-modifier

I have 2 imported STL's which I am trying to use the Boolean modifier to subtract the object from the truck windscreen with not much success. When I apply the Boolean it leaves the object imbedded in the truck.
[image]

[image: Truck 01]
[image: Truck 02]

Comment: Hello it seems to work with Solver >Fast instead of Exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Solver > Fast* option seems to work, instead of *Exact*:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the answerer is just staring you in the face and you just don't see it. Another lesson learnt, thanks.